# Lock error when updating new document in ItemAdded

Tags: document-library, event-receivers

I'm trying to update an item when it is added to a document library.  I have an EventReceiver on my document library and I am using the `ItemAdded` event.  I am using the **New Document** button to create a Word doc.

I click save in word, and after the save is complete, my `ItemAdded` event triggers and runs the following.

```
listItem["Field"] = value;
listItem.SystemUpdate(false);
```

I get an error message stating: `The file <url> is locked for share use by <user>`.

This lock seems to persist until the file is closed in Word.

I found [SPLockType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.splocktype.aspx) in the MSDN which states.

> The file is locked for editing by one or more users. Any of these users can save the file if the correct lock identifier is specified. Other users are prevented from saving the file until the lock is released.

Which makes me think I should be able to do this if I can specify the lock id, but I don't know how to do that.

Otherwise, is there a way to delay my code from running until the lock is released?  I don't see any methods on `SPItemEventReceiver` that appear to apply.

Comment: Do you have already a solution for this problem because I have the same problem. I think it maybe can be something with run with elevated priveliges to solve it but i'm not sure.

Comment: I don't remember which solution I ended up using and I don't have access to the code anymore.  However, a SPD Workflow will wait until the lock is released to run, or the logic can be moved to the ItemUpdated event, which is triggered after the lock is released.

Answer (score 0):

listItem.SystemUpdate(false) is supposed to not observe 'Locked' state introduced by Microsoft Office Word.

There is no specific time to wait until lock is released as it can be automatically extended. More detailed [post](http://andrewwburns.com/2012/07/25/sharepoint-check-out-vs-lock/) explains the difference between 'Checked Out' / 'Locked' and the reason for both.